# Нестягнені форми прикметників є нормативними в українській мові?

Tags: прикметники, морфологія

Часто в художній літературі зустрічаємо нестягнені форми прикметників: зеленеє жито, добрая людина і т.д. В [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/zelenyj) поряд з прикметником **зелений** бачимо коротку форму **ЗЕЛЕН**, але не має поряд форми **ЗЕЛЕНЕЄ**(напр.):

> ЗЕЛЕ́НИЙ, поет. ЗЕЛЕН, а, е.

Чи є нестягнені форми прикметників нормативними? Оскільки, знайшла інформацію [Історична граматика](https://www.twirpx.com/file/2163787/):

> Займенникові прикметники в українській мові стягувалися, і в сучасній мові вживаються займенникові стягнені прикметники: *добрая>добра*. Нестягнені форми 
>   вживаються у фольклорі: *зеленеє жито.*

Але, зрозуміло, що багато слів, які зустрічаємо у фольклорі не є нормативними в сучасній мові.

Answer (score 5):

Нестягнена форма певних прикметників є *стилістичною* нормою фольклору і поезії, а також нормою для деяких говорів (степовий, східнополіський). Також для точності щодо правил слововживання наведу цитату:

> У сучасній українській літературній мові повна (нестягнена) форма
>   поширена в називному відмінку однини тільки в прикметниках чоловічого
>   роду (червоний, добрий, синій, довгошиїй, дев'ятий). В окремих
>   прикметниках жіночого і середнього роду така форма використовується
>   здебільшого з стилістичною метою (надання мові піднесеного й
>   урочистого характеру) в народній творчості та художньо-поетичній
>   літературі: Я ще молод козак, вислужуюся: за два коні воронії, за дві
>   шаблі золотії (Нар. тв.). А щедрая матусенька раділа у садку (П. Т.).

[Studopedia](http://studopedia.com.ua/1_21249_styagneni-ta-nestyagneni-formi-povnih-prikmetnikiv.html)

Власне, тут питання, вузько чи широко розуміти норму. Якщо вузько, скажімо як для вживання в офіційному документі, то нестягненим формам прикметника там не місце, хіба що в складі цитати.

Answer (score 1):

[Уривок з «Нового довідника. Українська мова. Українська література» (2008, Київ, ТОВ «Казка»), с. 212–213](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=12869):

> Повні форми прикметників бува­ють *стягнені* (*добра, добре, доб­рі*) і *нестягнені* (*добрая, добреє, добрії*).
>
> Нестягнену форму можуть мати іменники [тут, імовірно, описка, малося на увазі: прикметники — примітка моя] жіночого і середнього роду в називному та знахідному відмінку однини та в називному множини.
>
> `ПОРІВНЯЙТЕ!`
>          `Стягнена       │         Нестягнена`         
>   *`-а (я), -е (є), -і (ї)│-ая (яя), -еє (єє), -ії (її)`*
>   *`висока, високе, високі│високая, високеє, високії`*   
>   *`синя, синє, сині      │синяя, синєє, синії`*         
>   *`чиста, чисте, чисті   │чистая, чистеє, чистиї`*      
>   *`дружня, дружнє, дружні│дружняя, дружнєє, дружнії`*
>
> Стягнені форми утворюються від нестягнених так: приголосний [*j*], що був між голосними в закінченнях, зник; два однакових голосних за­кінчення стяглися в один звук:
>   *веселаjя → веселаа → весела*;
>   *темнеjе → темнее → темне*.
>
> **Нестягнені форми прикметників уживаються в розмовно-побутовому стилі, фольклорі, а в художніх тво­рах виступають як засіб вираження врочистості, емоційної піднесеності й
>   стилізації під народнопісенну мову** [виділення напівжирним моє]:
>   *Ой, у святую неділеньку*
>   *Рано-пораненьку*
>   *Не сизії тумани уставали,*
>   *Не буйнії вітри повівали,*
>   *Не чорнії хмари наступали,*
>   *Не дрібнії дощі накрапали,*
>   *Коли три брати із города Азова,*
>   *Із турецької бусурменської*
>   *Великої неволі утікали…*
>   (Нар. тв.)
>   *Зоре моя вечірняя,*
>   *Зійди над горою,*
>   *Поговорим тихесенько*
>   *В неволі з тобою.*
>   *Там матір добрую мою*
>   *Ще молодую у могилу*
>   *Нужда та праця положила.*
>   *Оживуть степи, озера,*
>   *І не верстовії,*
>   *А вольнії, широкії*
>   *Скрізь шляхи святії*
>   *Простеляться.*
>   (З тв. Т. Шевченка.)